# Android best practice: is it ok to initialize the TextToSpeech engine on the main thread?

Tags: android, performance, profiling, text-to-speech

Is it ok to initialize the android [TextToSpeech](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech) object on the main thread? My understanding is that it should not be an issue creating the instance in `onCreate()` since [TextToSpeech.OnInitListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.OnInitListener) is an asynchronous callback and it will not slow down the UI. Is this assumption correct?

Comment: Yes i also think its correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is: Yes that is correct. :D